# CSS change property only for one row in table without i column

Tags: css

So what I need to do is change the alignment of the text in the 4th column, but without the first row in the table. And I can only do it in CSS.

I tried using

`tbody>tr>:nth-child(4)`

but I can't find how to skip the first row

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m4Nc.png)

the red cells in the table are the ones I'm talking about

Comment: `tbody>tr>:nth-child(4)` doesn't need the second immediate-child selector (`>`)... `tbody>tr:nth-child(4)` would target correctly. . . you want: `tr>td:last-child{ background-color: #f00 }  tr:first-child>td:last-child { background-color: transparent }`

Comment: nth-child starts at 0, this targets 1st row, 4th column: `tbody tr:nth-child(0) td:nth-child(3)` but see above for minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `:not()` pseudo selector.

```css
td {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tbody>tr:not(:first-of-type) :nth-child(4) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm very grateful. You don't even know how much time I spent frogging to come up with something and here you just add ":not(:first-type-of)"